# PHP: Generate ordered IDs that has no zeros and ones

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, serial-number

I want to create ordered numbers from 2 to whatever with no zero's and ones.

e.g 1, 10, 11, 15, 41, 50, 60, 61, etc these are invalid number

My try:

```
for($i=0, $ii=1000; $i<$ii; $i++){
     if($i%11){
        continue;
     }
}
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the numbers as strings and search for the chars "0" and "1".

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
  if(strpos((string) $i, '0') !== false) continue; // contains 0
  if(strpos((string) $i, '1') !== false) continue; // contains 1

  echo $i . "\n";
}
```

Please note that `strpos()` returns the position of the first occurence of the search string (aka needle) within the given string (aka haystack) or `false` if no match is found. This is why you have to compare the result of `strpos()` with `!== false` as a result of `0` would be considered to be `false` too if just using `== false`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php for a detailed documentation with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an integer, convert it to an octal string, and then increase the value of each digit by 2. I'm not a PHP programmer, so I'll give you the pseudocode.

```
foo = 1
octFoo = decoct(foo)
// at this point, octFoo is equal to 1

// Now go through each character in octFoo and increase it by 2.
// So 0 becomes 2, 1 becomes 3, etc.
```

Given the number 8, `octFoo` would be `10`, and the final result would be `32`.

You could do this without the intermediate octal step if you wanted to write your own integer-to-string routine. Rather than using the digits 0 through 7, use the digits 2 through 9.